# Node Express Mongoose array isn't populated with referenced model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've been trying to add a related model in an array of model. But when I test the api, the array is always empty. And I've been looking around for answers in Stackoverflow and google but nothing worked.

**SCHEMAS & MODELS**

```
let UserSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  avatar: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  dob: String,
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  createdAt: Date,
  accounts: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' }] // --> this is what I want to fill
});

let AccountSchema = new Schema({
  createdAt: Date,
  accountNumber: { type: Number, required: true },
  balance: Number,
  daysLeft: Number,
  nextMonthPayment: Number,
  paymentType: String,
  currentPlan: {
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    usage: {
      used: Number,
      left: Number,
      total: Number,
      meta: {
        trafficData: [{
          date: Date,
          amount: Number,
          download: Number,
          upload: Number
        }],
      }
    }
  },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
});

User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
Account = mongoose.model('Account', AccountSchema);
// end: SCHEMAS & MODELS
```

**PROCESSING**

```
// POST
router.post('/accounts', (req, res) => {
  user = new User({
    title: 'Ms',
    firstName: 'Paula',
    lastName: 'Testerson',
    username: '@paulatest',
    avatar: '',
    email: 'paula.test@emailtest.com',
    dob: '01 January 1989',
    password: 'test123',
    createdAt: Date.now()
  });

  account = new Account({
    createdAt: Date.now(),
    accountNumber: 7651234,
    balance: 91.75,
    daysLeft: 23,
    nextMonthPayment: 19.57,
    paymentType: 'debit card',
    currentPlan: {
      name: 'Fast Furious',
      usage: {
        used: 10356,
        left: 89644,
        total: 100000,
        meta: {
          trafficData: [{
            date: 'Fri Dec 22 2017 14:42:14 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
            amount: 100.50,
            download: 20.65,
            upload: 16.90
          }],
        }
      }
    },
    user: user._id
  });

  user.save((err) => {
    if (err) { res.send(err); }

    account.save(err => {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json({
        message: 'Account created!',
        status: 'created'
      });
    });

    user.find({})
      .populate('accounts') // --> this is not working somehow
      .exec()
      .then((users) => {
        console.log('User - ', users);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('User err - ', err);
      });
  });
});

// GET
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Welcome to accounts api' });
});

router.get('/accounts', (req, res) => {
  Account.find((err, accounts) => {
    if (err) { res.send(err); }
    res.json(accounts);
  });
});

router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  User.find({})
    .populate('accounts') // --> this is not working somehow
    .exec((err, users) => {
      if (err) { res.send(err); }
      res.json(users);
    });
});
```

That's what I've done so far and still the `User.accounts` is not populated. What's the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The soultion for your problem is defined below:

```
router.post('/accounts', (req, res) => {
    user = new User({
        title: 'Ms',
        firstName: 'Paula',
        lastName: 'Testerson',
        username: '@paulatest',
        avatar: '',
        email: 'paula.test@emailtest.com',
        dob: '01 January 1989',
        password: 'test123',
        createdAt: Date.now()
    });

    account = new Account({
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        accountNumber: 7651234,
        balance: 91.75,
        daysLeft: 23,
        nextMonthPayment: 19.57,
        paymentType: 'debit card',
        currentPlan: {
            name: 'Fast Furious',
            usage: {
                used: 10356,
                left: 89644,
                total: 100000,
                meta: {
                    trafficData: [{
                        date: 'Fri Dec 22 2017 14:42:14 GMT+0000 (GMT)',
                        amount: 100.50,
                        download: 20.65,
                        upload: 16.90
                    }],
                }
            }
        },
        user: user._id
    });

    user.accounts.push(account._id); // you have to pushed the account  id into newly created user doc
    user.save((err, savedUser) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        account.save(err => {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }

            // It is better approach to use populate rather than finding the user by using .find() method
            User.populate(savedUser, {
                path: 'accounts'
            }, (err, populatedUser) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                }
                console.log(populatedUser);

                // send response here //

            });
        });
    });
});
```

Advice: 
It is a best practise to make one relation, in your case you are referencing account in User model and user in account model, which means a double ref. So to handle this you should ref user in account model or account in user model not both.

Answer (score 0):

populate isn't the right tool for the job in this case. Mongoose has specific array commands for working with sub docs. In this case what you want is to push an item onto the array in order to save it. Once updated you need to save the document.

```
User.find({}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) { return console.error(err) }
  doc.accounts.push(someaccount._id)
  doc.save()
})
```

the docs for working with sub documents are [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)